# How to read an index which runs over all the elements of a list in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I have a basic question here. I want to generate random positions, with a minimum distance between them. Nevertheless, the most I have achieve is a position list where the element "n" is at a larger distance than the element "n-1", but it does not care about all the previous "n-2,3,4,..." elements. This is my code so far:

```
sample = input('How many elements do you want?')
X = np.linspace(200,1900) 
Y = np.linspace(200,1900)
Xin = np.random.choice(X,1)
Yin = np.random.choice(Y,1)
dmin = 1000
i = 1
a = [ ]
Xprev = [Xin]
Yprev = [Yin]
while (i<sample+1):
    Xal = np.random.choice(X,1) 
    Yal = np.random.choice(Y,1)
    if sqrt((Xal-Xprev[i-1])**2+(Yal-Yprev[i-1]**2) > dmin:
        Xfin = Xal
        Yfin = Yal
        Xprev.append(Xfin)
        Yprev.append(Yfin)
        a_s = zip(Xfin,Yfin)
        a.append(a_s)
        out = vstack(a)
        i = i+1
    else:

        i=i
```

I think what I need is to change the index of Xprev in the if statement, for an index that runs over all and each of the elements of the X,Yprev lists. Could you explain me how to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question looks very similar to this: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/158357-create-random-points-in-a-rectangular-domain-but-with-minimum-separation-distance

The simple way to do this would be to iterate over the indices from `0` to `i-1` and check that the condition holds for all of them.

```
if all((Xal-Xprev[j])**2+(Yal-Yprev[j]**2) > dmin for j in xrange(i)):
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can use numpy arrays to express this more cleanly.

```
dmin2 = dmin**2  # Compute square of minimum distance
points = np.zeros((sample, 2))
points[0] = np.random.choice(X), np.random.choice(Y)
i = 1
while i < sample:
    # Get a trial point
    point = np.array((np.random.choice(X), np.random.choice(Y)))

    # Check minimum distance to existing points
    if np.min(np.sum(np.square(points[:i] - point), 1)) > dmin2:
        points[i] = point
        i += 1
```

Comment: Ohh, I see. Great! Thank you very much! I still had problems with the first option, but then, using your second idea, everything went better!

Comment: @Enrique I just noticed a small bug in the code -- you need to square `dmin` since the left had side of the comparison is computing the square of the distance.  This is more efficient than taking the square root each time.